# reading css transformation matrices on dom element is giving conflicting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I have the following dom element:

```
<div class="UEdit-transformable" unselectable="on" style="transform: matrix(2.21698, 0, 0, 2.21698, 0, 0); user-select: none;">
```

In the web inspector, both the css styles and computed properties show the following transform values.

[image]

In javascript, I'm trying to read the transform values on this element. I've tried to read this value in multiple ways, but here I am just logging out the style property.

```
console.log('style', domElement.style);
```

And the results confuse me since it seems to show conflicting matrix values for the transformation of that element - for example, 'MozTransform'.

[image]

When using jquery to read the transform via `$(domElement).css('transform')` I'm getting

```
matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)
```

and not what I'd expect:

```
matrix(2.2169811320754715,0,0,2.2169811320754715,0,0)
```

What's going on here? What's the most bullet-proof way to read in these transformation properties to get the values I expect?

Comment: Seems to work [fine](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPVbdj?editors=1010), perhaps you could post a reproducible demo showing the issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce it! It works fine for me except in the specific scenario I am facing. I am particularly confused by how the CSSStyleDeclaration logs and how the MozTransform values don't match. I noticed rolling over the little 'i' icon seems to imply that the below values are updated. I am pretty sure this is simply a race condition of trying to read the transform property before it is being set.